# How to check check all possible decodings for data

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, character-encoding

Very worried this question may be abused, but here goes!

My server is receiving some data through a GET request in the URL, which has been encoded in some manner, I thought it would be `base64` but that is not the case.

I would like to write a `js` function to accept this string and try all possible encodings/decodings.

Please help!

The data is in this sort of format: `ZHpuxRiviOUGeOKTKdw`

There is the potential it is encrypted, if that is the case I am not asking for help in decrypting it!

EDIT: my goal is not to write a perfect algorithm which can do this automatically - I simply want to try x top most popular decodings of this string and print them out.

Comment: From the sample, it doesn't appear that this is a character encoding issue. But do start by looking at the HTTP response headers, especially [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type). Please [edit] to add to your question.

Comment: Thank you Tom, nothing to report there.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do that, how would you know if `ZHpuxRiviOUGeOKTKdw` wasn't actually the string? If this is your server and this is data you're receiving then you should know how the string is encoded based on what your application does.

Comment: Yes you can do that! You can write a function to take this string and print out the output using an array of all possible decodings.

Comment: There are an infinite number of possible decodings and it's impossible to know which one gave you the right answer unless you already knew the answer ahead of time.

Comment: Guys, but I just want to check the 100 most popular and will review them manually.

Comment: You still haven't answered the question, how would you know what's correct? How do you know that the string you already have isn't the correct string? Why don't you know what kind of encoding your application is using? Your question is too vague, if you want to write something yourself and ask a specific question on how to decode a specific type of data then ask that, but you need to start somewhere other than "I want to brute force this encoded data"

Comment: You are saying what I want to do is wrong - rather than just helping achieve it. Why do you decide that? I want to write a function which wants to try all decodings and see if anything is correct. I do not care if you consider that to be incorrect.

Comment: This website isn't here for you to get people to write code for you. You asked a nonsensical question, offered no explanation as to what you're actually trying to achieve, and then you narrowed it down to "Well I just want to brute force 100 popular encoding methods", which is not what this website is for. If you have a particular question about code you wrote to achieve your goal, ask that.

Comment: Bob if the question is nonsensical move on and feel better. You opinion is not of interest to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191743/discussion-between-bob-dole-and-dendog).